# Explanation on the Proof of $W(t)=W(t_0)\exp\left(\int_{t_0}^{t} \text{tr}(\underline{A}(s)) \ ds\right)$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, dynamical-systems

In my study of Floquet Theory, I have been given a sketch proof on the following definition of the Wronskian, $$W(t)=W(t_0)\exp\left(\int_{t_0}^{t} \text{tr}(\underline{A}(s)) \ ds\right).$$

> Proof:\begin{align}
> \underline{x}(t)&=\underline{x}(t_0)+(t-t_0)\underline{x'}(t_0)+O(t-t_0)^2 \\
> &=\underline{x}(t_0)+(t-t_0)\underline{A}(t_0)\underline{x}(t_0)+O(t-t_0)^2,
> \end{align}
>   as $\underline{x'}=\underline{A}\underline{x}$ and thus $\underline{X'}=\underline{A}\underline{X}$ where $\underline{X}$ denotes the fundamental matrix.
>   Now, \begin{align}
> W(t)&=\det(\underline{X}(t)) \\
> &=\det((\underline{I}+(t-t_0)\underline{A}(t_0))\underline{X}(t_0)+O(t-t_0)^2) \tag{1}\\
> &=W(t_0)(1+(t-t_0)\text{tr}(\underline{A}(t_0))+O(t-t_0)^2 \tag{2}.
> \end{align}
>   Using Taylor expansion:
>   $$W(t)=W(t_0)+(t-t_0)W'(t_0)+O(t-t_0)^2. \tag{3}$$ Letting $t\rightarrow t_0$, $$W'(t)=W(t)\text{tr}(\underline{A}(t))\implies W(t)=W(t_0)\exp\left(\int_{t_0}^{t} \text{tr}(\underline{A}(s)) \ ds\right)$$

There are many parts that I do not understand. Are there any resources that could help explain this? For instance, how is the last line derived (where did $W'(t)$ appear from)?

Comment: This forum is a resource that can help, but you're going to have to be more specific about which parts you don't understand. For instance, do you know about big-O notation? And Taylor expansions? Do you know $\det(I+tA)\approx 1+t{\rm tr}(A)$? As for the last line, the expansion of $W(t)$ yields $$\frac{W(t)-W(t_0)}{t-t_0}=W(t_0){\rm tr} A(t_0)+O(t-t_0). $$ Taking $t\to t_0$ yields $W'(t_0)=W(t_0){\rm tr}A(t_0)$ (then they just replace $t_0$ with $t$). You can solve this differential equation with the integrating factor method. (I can post this as an answer, unless you have more questions.)

Comment: @arctictern Thanks for the response. I do know a bit about big-O notation and have a good grasp on Taylor expansions. I think they resource used Jacobi's formula to approximate $1+t\text{tr}(A)$. One question I do have is still on the expansion of $W(t)$.Have you used L'Hopital's rule on $$\frac{W(t)-W(t_0)}{t-t_0}?$$ I'm unsure of where $W'(t)$ comes from. I think I can solve the ODE, but not sure how it originates.

Comment: Not l'Hopital, but the very definition of a derivative: $$ W'(t_0):=\lim_{t\to t_0} \frac{W(t)-W(t_0)}{t-t_0}. $$ Then they replaced $t_0$ in $W'(t_0)=W(t_0){\rm tr}A(t_0)$ (the RHS comes from the expansion for $W(t)$) with $t$ to get the same formula but written for $W'(t)$ instead of $W'(t_0)$. And $\det(I+tX)=1+t\,{\rm tr}(A)+O(t^2)$ is not quite as sophisticated as Jacobi's formula, but sure (note you can prove this one more easily using the Leibniz formula for determinant and the product rule for derivatives).

Comment: @arctictern Ah I see. I don't quite understand the significance between step $(1)$ and $(2)$. By writing down the Taylor expansion, is it possible to equate the coefficients of $(t-t_0)$ to determine that $W'(t_0)=W(t_0)\text{tr}(A(t_0))$? Why do we need the Taylor expansion?

Comment: Yes it is possible to equate coefficients of $(t-t_0)$ to get the differential equation. Equivalently, subtract $W(t_0)$ from both sides of $(1)$, then divide by $(t-t_0)$, then let $t\to t_0$ and you get $W'(t_0)=$blah.

Comment: @arctictern From step $(1)$, 
\begin{align} 
W(t)&=W(t_0)(1+(t-t_0)\text{tr}(\underline{A}(t_0))+O(t-t_0)^2  \\
\frac{W(t)-W(t_0)}{t-t_0}&=W(t_0)\text{tr}(\underline{A}(t_0))+O(t-t_0) \\
\lim_{t\to\ t_0}\frac{W(t)-W(t_0)}{t-t_0}&=W(t_0)\text{tr}(\underline{A}(t_0)) \\
W'(t)&=W(t_0)\text{tr}(\underline{A}(t_0))
\end{align} Does this mean that we don't require step $(2)$? I don't really see why the step is necessary.

Comment: You don't require writing out (2), but they seemed to use it by comparing coefficients in Taylor expansions, which is also a natural and valid (and arguably equivalent) thing to do.

Comment: @arctictern are you able to post your solution of $W'(t_0)=W(t_0)\text{tr}(\underline{A}(t_0))$ using an integrating factor? I've realised you can't rely on the characteristic equation.

Comment: Sure, it's separable, so divide to get $W'(t)/W(t)={\rm tr}A(t)$, then integrate from $t_0$ to $t$ to get $\ln W(t)-\ln W(t_0)=\int_{t_0}^t {\rm tr}A(s)ds$. Can you take it from here? It's actually easier than characteristic equations!

Comment: @arctictern Yep, thanks!! :)

Comment: @arctictern Just one final query. How do we move from step $(1)$ to step $(2)$ (once I understand this, I fully understand the entire proof)? Maybe answer this point in the answer selection so I can tick it. I've included my thoughts.  
\begin{align}
W(t)&=\det((\underline{I}+(t-t_0)\underline{A}(t_0))\underline{X}(t_0)+O(t-t_0)^2) \\
&=\det((\underline{I}+(t-t_0)\underline{A}(t_0))\underline{X}(t_0))+\det (O(t-t_0)^2) \\
&=\det(\underline{X}(t_0))\det((\underline{I}+(t-t_0)\underline{A}(t_0))+O|(t-t_0)^2| \\
&=W(t_o)(1+(t-t_0)\underline{A}(t_0)+O(t-t_0)^2)+O|(t-t_0)^2|
\end{align}

Comment: It seems like you're using $\det(X+Y)=\det(X)+\det(Y)$, which is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, firstly the Taylor series expansion of $X(t)$ near $t=t_0$ is given by

$$X(t)=X(t_0)+X'(t_0)(t-t_0)+\mathcal{O}\big((t-t_0)^2\big).$$

Next, we can use $X'(t_0)=A(t_0)X(t_0)$ to get

$$X(t)=X(t_0)\big(I+(t-t_0)A(t_0)\big)+\mathcal{O}\big((t-t_0)^2\big). $$

To take the determinant of both sides, we can use $\det(X(t_0)B)=\det(X(t_0))\det B$:

$$ \begin{array}{ll} W(t) & =W(t_0)\det\big(I+(t-t_0)A(t_0)+\mathcal{O}((t-t_0)^2)\big). \\ & =W(t_0)\det\big(I+(\color{Red}{t-t_0})\big[\color{Blue}{A(t_0)+\mathcal{O}(t-t_0)}\big]\big) \end{array}$$

Note when you factor $X(t_0)$ out of $\mathcal{O}((t-t_0)^2)$, you just get $\mathcal{O}((t-t_0)^2)$ since $X(t_0)$ is constant.

Next we can use the fact $\det(I+\color{Red}{\varepsilon} \color{Blue}{X})=1+\color{Red}{\varepsilon}\mathrm{tr}(\color{Blue}{X})+\mathcal{O}(\color{Red}{\varepsilon}^2)$ (which follows from the Leibniz formula for the determinant, itself the final result of expansion by minors), where $\varepsilon=t-t_0$. Note factoring $(t-t_0)$ out of $\mathcal{O}((t-t_0)^2)$ will be $\mathcal{O}(t-t_0)$, but everything gets absorbed back in the end:

$$ \begin{array}{ll} W(t) & =W(t_0)\big[1+(\color{Red}{t-t_0})\mathrm{tr}\big(\color{Blue}{A(t_0)+\mathcal{O}(t-t_0)}\big)+\mathcal{O}((\color{Red}{t-t_0})^2)\big] \\ & =W(t_0)\big[1+(t-t_0)\mathrm{tr}\,A(t_0)+\mathcal{O}((t-t_0)^2)\big]. \end{array}$$

On the other hand, the Taylor expansion of $W(t)$ is

$$ W(t)=W(t_0)+W'(t_0)(t-t_0)+\mathcal{O}((t-t_0)^2). $$

Equating coefficients of $(t-t_0)$ yields $W'(t_0)=W(t_0)\mathrm{tr}\,A(t_0)$. Equivalently, the other expansion of $W(t)$ we can subtract $W(t_0)$ from both sides, divide by $t-t_0$ to obtain

$$ \frac{W(t)-W(t_0)}{t-t_0}=W(t_0)\mathrm{tr}\,A(t_0)+\mathcal{O}(t-t_0). $$

Letting $t\to t_0$ yields $W'(t_0)=W(t_0)\mathrm{tr}\,A(t_0)$. Now replace $t_0$ with $t$ (since it was arbitrary):

$$ W'(t)=A(t)W(t). $$

This is a separable ODE which can be solved with the integrating factor method. First divide by $W(t)$ and then notice $W'(t)/W(t)$ is the derivative of $\ln W(t)$, so integrate from $t_0$ to $t$:

$$ W'(t)/W(t)=\mathrm{tr}\,A(t) $$

$$ \ln W(t)-\ln W(t_0)=\int_{t_0}^t \mathrm{tr}\,A(s)\,\mathrm{d}s $$

Notice so the LHS is $\ln(W(t)/W(t_0))$, so exponentiate and multiply by $W(t_0)$ to get

$$ W(t)=W(t_0)\exp\left(\int_{t_0}^t \mathrm{tr}\,A(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\right). $$

Comment: I don't understand how we can use the identity $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. If we had that $$X(t)=X(t_0)\left(I+(t-t_0)A(t_0)+\mathcal{O}((t-t_0)^2)\right),$$ then I would understand, as $A=X(t_0)$ and $B=\left(I+(t-t_0)A(t_0)+\mathcal{O}((t-t_0)^2)\right)$. But $\mathcal{O}((t-t_0)^2)$ is not multiplied by $X(t_0)$, so then how does $$\det(X(t_0))$$ appear at the front of $$\det\left(I+(t-t_0)A(t_0)+\mathcal{O}((t-t_0)^2)\right)?$$

Comment: @sjmb We *do* have that first equation in your comment though! Like I said in the answer, we factor $X(t_0)$ out of ${\cal O}((t-t_0)^2)$ since $X(t_0)$ is a constant (and invertible). Note $X(t_0){\cal O}((t-t_0)^2)={\cal O}((t-t_0)^2)$.

Comment: Oh I see. Sorry for the all the questions. Is factoring out this constant a property of big-$\mathcal{O}$ notation? I think my lack of understanding of big-$\mathcal{O}$ has let me down for this proof.

Comment: Yes. The notation ${\cal O}(f(t))$ means "some matrix function $M(t)$ such that $|M(t)|\le C|f(t)|$ for some constant $C$ and $t$ in a nbhd of $0$," where $|M(t)|$ is some matrix norm of $M(t)$, or *equivalently* $|m_{ij}(t)|\le K|f(t)|$ for each matrix entry $m_{ij}(t)$ and constant $K$ and $t$ in a nbhd of $0$. If $M(t)$ is any function which can be described as $\mathcal{O}(f(t))$, then so is any constant matrix times $M(t)$.